# forward const reference through function

Tags: c++

I just was wondering, is following code ill-defined:

```
const int& foo(const int& a)
{
  return a;
}

int main()
{
  const int& b = foo(5);
  // some actions with b...
}
```

Are these actions well-defined, when we returned const reference to rvalue through the function?

Comment: Does it compile and build?

Comment: I think you mean "is it well-**defined**"...

Comment: yes, is this program well-defined?

Comment: No, you have a dangling reference to a temporary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're returning a reference to a temporary that goes out of scope after the function call ends.

This is not a good idea and using the reference after the call invokes [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

---

If you were half-hoping for the *life-time extension of temporaries when bound to a const reference* rule to save here, keep in mind this **only** works iff the *temporary* is *directly* bound to the reference:

```
const int& a = 5;
b = foo(a); // would be fine
```

Comment: Does only one const reference prolong temporary object lifetime?

Comment: Yes, and only if the temporary is directly bound to it. So, not: `const char& uhoh = std::string("breakage")[0]` either

Comment: @sehe But isn't in a sense what is happening in the function? 5 is bounded to `a` then, `a` is bounded to `b`? Is there any good reason for non-transitivity of const-ref bounding to temporaries?

Comment: @vsoftco the temporary binds to the reference that is the function argument. The lifetime of this variable ends when the function returns. So, the extension ends too. (The non-transitivity is simply because at this point the compiler can no longer tell whether the reference received was bound to a temporary or jsut a regular reference. In other words: it's impossible to know everything. Conversely, how does the compiler know that the reference returned, happens to be to the temporary passed in? And consider this:

Comment: [...] [non-deterministic paths](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a66537339a7b078c)* make it really evident that the compiler _cannot_ know. It runs into the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) /cc @vsoftco

Comment: @sehe, so the process is 3 step: bound to `a`, return, then assign to `b`. And the problem is that between the return and assignment to `b`, `a` ceases to exist, is this correct? I first thought that the return statement just takes the temporary and binds it to `b`, but it seems that there is this extra "time step" in which the object return is dangling.

Comment: Yes, or even before the assignment to b - that's implementation defined AFAICT. Re.: _"I first thought that the return statement just takes the temporary and binds it to b"_ - no at that time there _is no temporary_! There's just a `const&` object. However, ***[this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a747f518ed14901)*** is fine, because the return value is a new temporary _of it's own_